# Как добавить опцию "Прикрепить запись" для custom post type без плагинов?

Tags: wordpress

Как добавить опцию "Прикрепить запись" для custom post type без плагинов?

немного уточню вопрос - мне нужно добавить checkbox в админке "Прикрепить запись" для custom post type

Comment: sticky_posts https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-postov-i-stranits

Comment: немного уточню вопрос - мне нужно добавить checkbox в админке "Прикрепить запись" для custom post type

Comment: Ничего себе немного уточню)) потом отвечу)

Comment: Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вкратце так https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign, имхо, не очень рациональное решение для настроек отдельных статей. Как с ними потом работать?

Comment: @alenkins да непонятно же, чего он хочет. Один чекбокс, чтобы пиикрепить один пост - тогда страница настроек. Кучу постов сделать прилепленными - тогда в метабоксы надо уходить. Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Он спросил, как добавить опцию, я ответил.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это да, с формулировками вопросов по метке "wordpress" тут какая-то постоянная беда

Answer (score 0):

Вам помогут функции `add_meta_box()` ([документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)) для создания метабокса, `update_post_meta()` ([документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)) для сохранения выбранного значения и `get_post_meta()` ([документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)) для получения сохранённого значения поля.

В общих чертах получится нечто подобное:

```
function my_post_type_custom_settings($post) {
    $flag = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_custom_field', 1);
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="my_custom_custom_field" value="on" <?php echo $flag == 'on' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>> <span>Пояснение к чекбоксу</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
function my_post_type_custom_settings_update($post_id) {
    /* перед сохранением изменений выполните все необходимые проверки */

    $extra_field = $_POST['dont_create_turbo_page']; /* не забудьте о проверке и фильтрации полученных данных */
    if (empty($extra_field))
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_custom_field');
    if ($extra_field)
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_custom_field', $extra_field);
    return $post_id;
}
if(is_admin()){
    add_meta_box('post_custom_settings', 'Настройки записи', 'my_post_type_custom_settings', 'my_post_type', 'side', 'high');
    add_action('save_post', 'my_post_type_custom_settings_update');
}
```